# Mojolicious Export does not work with Mojo::Loader

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I had exported some constants from my module. In my script I am loading my module using  Mojo::Loader

my module

```
use constant FALSE        => 0;
use constant TRUE         => 1;

our @EXPORT = qw(FALSE TRUE);
```

In my script.

```
Mojo::Loader->new->load($my_module_name);
```

I was able to use my module in my script, but the constants that I exported were not accessible in my script. If I load my module with use clause. I was able to use the exported constants.

Any idea how to fix this and import the constants into my script.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your module code where you export your constants.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the Mojo module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the code for Mojo::Loader and it turns out it cannot import stuff. It only does a `require` (in a string eval), but not a `use`. A quick grep of the source reveals that there is no `import` whatsoever, so you will need to call `Your::Module->import` yourself.

[Here's a link](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-4.67/lib/Mojo/Loader.pm#L22) to the relevant part of the source code and a quote:

> ```
> sub load {
>   my ($self, $module) = @_;
>
>   # Check module name
>   return 1 if !$module || $module !~ /^\w(?:[\w:']*\w)?$/;
>
>   # Load
>   return undef if $module->can('new') || eval "require $module; 1";
>
>   # Exists
>   return 1 if $@ =~ /^Can't locate \Q@{[class_to_path $module]}\E in \@INC/;
>
>   # Real error
>   return Mojo::Exception->new($@);
> }
> ```

---

There is something interesting going on here. If you `use foo`, the import works with constants.

```
use foo;
print 'True: ', TRUE;
```

However:

```
require foo; 
foo->import;
print 'True: ', TRUE;
```

This will produce a warning `Bareword "TRUE" not allowed while "strict subs" in use`. So we put `TRUE()` to make it look less like a bareword. A constant is a sub after all. Now it will work. The same goes for doing `Mojo::Loader->load('foo')`.

If you wrap a `BEGIN` block around the `require` and `import`, you can omit the parenthesis.

Thus, if you want to export constants, add parenthesis to where you call them if you want to keep using Mojo::Loader.

Comment: I also tried to do my_module->import(); but it did not help. Still constants are not accessible

Comment: Regarding the `BEGIN` edit: I believe that has to do with what barewords Perl recognizes as subs internally at compile time, but I cannot explain it. Maybe someone else can?

Comment: I found a reference to half an explanation pretty far down in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END saying *"Because the use statement implies a BEGIN block, the importing of semantics happens as soon as the use statement is compiled, before the rest of the file is compiled. This is how it is able to function as a pragma mechanism, and also how modules are able to declare subroutines that are then visible as list or unary operators for the rest of the current file."*.